# Astronauts Shot Down, hidden by SF fans

Tags: story-identification

Read in the late 1990s in e-book format; don't remember the acquisition source.

A new ice age has started, and the ice is down to roughly the US/Canada border. The US government - and by implication, much of the rest of the world - is essentially controlled by the Greens, and most of what *we* would consider modern technology is considered unacceptable (though some is "acceptable" to the extent that it allows the government to keep control over the populace). Science fiction, while not actually illegal, is taken as a sign of viewing "unacceptable" technology favorably, and can lead to "re-education" (in a distinctly Soviet style).

A pair of astronauts is attempting to scoop atmosphere to sustain their space habitat, and get shot down, landing on the ice. They are rescued by some "underground" SF fans, and the story centers around the attempts to keep the rescued astronauts out of the government's hands - and eventually morphs into a project to get them home to the space habitat, in spite of the government. There is a "Fen underground railway" of sorts, with signs that fen will recognize but non-fen wouldn't, which are references to what I'd consider 'classic' SF.

I never actually finished the book; that's as far as I'd gotten before a computer crash took out my copy of the e-book. Thus I ask...

What book was I reading?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[Fallen Angels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallen_Angels_(science_fiction_novel)) by  Larry Niven, Jerry Pournelle, and Michael Flynn.

From [here:](http://www.baen.com/fallen-angels.html)

> IT ALL HAPPENED SO FAST
>
> One minute the two space Hab astronauts were scoop-diving the
>   atmosphere, the next they'd been shot down over the North Dakota
>   Glacier and were the object of a massive manhunt by the United States
>   government.
>
> That government, dedicated to saving the environment from the evils of
>   technology, had been voted into power because everybody knew that the 
>   Green House Effect had to be controlled, whatever the cost. But who
>   would have thought that the cost of ending pollution would include not
>   only total government control of day-to-day life, but the onset of a
>   new Ice Age
>
> Stranded in the anti-technological heartland of America, paralyzed by
>   Earth's gravity, the "Angels" had no way back to the Space Habs, the
>   last bastions of high technology and intellectual freedom on or over
>   the Earth. But help was on its way, help from the most unlikely
>   sources ....

Comment: If you look in the dictionary under "fan service", it lists this book.

Comment: @OrganicMarble What dictionary is that? Does *Fallen Angels* have illustrations?

Comment: It was an attempt at humor.

Comment: @user14111 - in case you haven't read it, the book was written with an awfully large number of fannish in-jokes, references to real fans, and things that people outside of the (old-style worldcon-going fanzine-reading-and-probably-writing hardcore) SF fan community are unlikely to understand.  I mean, I consider myself pretty well acquainted with that community for an outsider to it (e.g. regularly I read the blogs of several well-known members of it) and I had to research quite a few things to understand them.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - With reference to "don't remember the acquisition source" IIRC the ebook was included in the CD that came free with one of the David Weber Honor Harrington books, so if you didn't specifically purchase it then it's likely this was where you got it from.

Comment: ... Yes, just checked, it's on the CD that came with *War of Honor* (which is archived online [here](http://baencd.freedoors.org/Discs/Baen%2001/index.htm) - listed under "Friends of Honor").

Comment: @Jules ... Dayum! I _have_ that CD - in fact, _all_ the Baen CDs... Maybe it's time to actually start rummaging them... :)

Answer (score 12):

Think this is what you're looking for.

## [*Fallen Angels*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallen_Angels_(science_fiction_novel)), by  Larry Niven, Jerry Pournelle, and Michael Flynn

[image: cover]

From Wikipedia:

> Astronauts from the orbital society fly a modified scramjet, redesigned to harvest nitrogen from the Earth's atmosphere. Government policy declares that these ships are responsible for the ice age, so the scramjet is shot down with a surface-to-air missile. The pilot and copilot, an Earth-born American named Alex MacLeod and a space-born Russo-American named Gordon Tanner, are forced to crash land in Canada atop the glaciers.
> Upon hearing of this, the fan underground embarks on a rescue mission - a group of fans rides north through the Dakotas to rescue the astronauts before they can be apprehended by the Government.
> [...]
> Upon finally reaching their van, the rescuers flee to a small science fiction convention of some 50 fans at a mansion owned by one of their own.

I recalled this story from memory.